# How to download images in Android Repository Pattern MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, repository

I'm developing an android app, and I need to save some images from url to the smartphone internal memory. Now in the repository I'm using file output stream and retrieving the uri with the Android FileProvider, with the application context, and store the as string in the Room Database. But this approach breaks the MVVM pattern, because repository shouldn't know anything about context. Should I call a service from the Activity/Fragment (maybe foreground so the download will finish even if app is killed)? There are other methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could just resolve the `uri` to a `ByteArray` or any other format you prefer where you have the context (activity or fragment), and pass it down that way to Room

Comment: Thank's for the comment! My application download from google places api the data of nearby places, and of that places I need to download the images and provide uri, back to view in order to set them to an ImageView. Doing the way you are suggesting I should get json in the repo, pass json up to the view, download images, and back to repo to save The Uri in the room database?

Comment: Ah, you you'll get back a `json`, where you get back the parameters of the images. I think you can just save the `photo_reference: String` of every image in Room.
And use an image loading library (for ex: https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load the image with a url

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I have to persist this photo, not only load it (for this I have my own class with memory and disk caching and it works just fine).

Comment: Usually we don't really save images in the db, if you want to persist locally, then I'd save it on the internal file storage

Comment: I get that, and I'm storing the Uris in the db, not the whole image, which I need to download, and here come the problem: I know how to download an image, but I need the context to get The Uri using file provider and the folder where save it.